# Hi I'm trying to write search functionality for my JSTree, but its showing error saying jypeerror $(...).jstree(...).search is not a function

Tags: javascript, jstree

```
 $('#temp').jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': userInfo
            },
            "plugins": ["search"]
        });
 $(".search-input").keyup(function() {
            var searchString = $(this).val();
            console.log(searchString);
            $('#temp').jstree('search', searchString);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Are you sure you have the library loaded before running this script? Also use `$('#temp').jstree().search(searchString);`.

Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/12atrpc7/)

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for the reply.... the library are not loading properly, can you tell me what is the issue??

Comment: If you know it doesn't load, you have to find out why. How do you link it to your page? Can you show your html? What are some errors you see in the browser console?

Comment: <div id="jstree">   
 </div>
 <input class="search-input form-control"  />
 <div id="temp">
 </div>    
  <script>
  var userInfo = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(jss)');
   $('#temp').jstree({
   'core': {
   'data': userInfo
    },
   "plugins": ["search"]
  });
  $(".search-input").keyup(function() {
   $.getScript("../../Scripts/jstree.min.js");
   $.getScript("../../Scripts/jstree.search.js");
   var searchString = $(this).val();
   console.log(searchString);
   //$('#temp').jstree('search', searchString);
  $('#temp').jstree(true).search(searchString);
  });

Comment: this is my code and i have downloaded the JSTree from the NuGet Pakages... and sorry for the presentation of code because iam new to this forum...

Comment: Did you include the jQuery javascript in this page? And then the jsTree javascript ?

Comment: HI Nikolay, yea i have added those two JS files